# Login redirect to dynami url - currently using Peter's Login Redirect

Tags: plugins

In my testing server I want the user to login when he is on a specific page and redirect back to the same page after login.

Here is the url the user is on :
`http://localhost/smsfhotproperty/complete-order/?pcode=890&pname=city-of-london-luxury-2-bedroom&step=1`

On this page I am having a basic wordpress login-form and I want the user to be redirected back to the same url after login.

Is this even possible. .. using this plugin or any other plugin .. ??

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Which plugin are you talking about? Please, note that [questions about third party plugins and plugin recomendations are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`wp_login_form()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) in your page. The login form will be generated with current URL as "after login redirect" parameter.